# Magento 2: admin ui-component tab view from issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml, uicomponent

In admin ui-component in a custom module, when I use page layout `admin-2columns-left` and

```
    <layout>
        <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
        <type>tabs</type>
    </layout>
```

in ui component form and commenting as

```
<!-- <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>-->
```

I got no data in edit mode. But when do reverse with using a single-column page layout, everything is fine.
Where I am doing wrong? Is it related to the field source issue? Because I use in form source as

```
<item name="source" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
```

for all field.